# Directory isn't being deleted

Tags: java, file, directory

What I want to happen is that when my project is completed the file that it created is deleted (so that all the files in it are deleted). What I do is

```
public void delete() {
    File f = new File (JavCapture.tmpLocation + "/tmp");
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        f.delete();
        System.out.println("Deleted tmp folder!");
    }
}
```

Not only does this not delete the folder but it also doesn't do the print statement which means (well what I assume it means) is that the directory doesn't exist but it does.

Also I make the location using this.

```
new File(tmpLocation + "/tmp").mkdir();
```

Comment: Print out the file location, it might not be what you think.

Comment: In order to delete a directory, you have to make sure that it is empty first, meaning there are no files in the directory.

Comment: Try catching the exception (enclose the code from creation of directory link to the delete call in try-catch block) and printing the stack trace. That could give you pointers on what's going wrong.

Comment: Is there any way I can delete all the contents in a directory? Because I need what's in the directory deleted but there are multiple files.

Comment: You can use the FileUtils.deleteDirectory method in Apache Commons IO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    public static boolean delete(final File directory){
    assert directory != null && directory.exists();
    if(!directory.isDirectory())
        return directory.delete();
    for(final File f : directory.listFiles())
        delete(f);
    return directory.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only empty folder can be deleted with this method. Write a recursive method to remove recursively all files first and then the parent folder.

```
 void delete(File file) {
   if (file.isFile) 
      file.delete();
   else {
      for (File sub: file.listFiles()) 
        delete(sub);
      file.delete();
   }
 }
```

Comment: You're method does not account for directories that might be inside a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the semantics for deleting a directory are different than those for deleting a file. Usually, you need to recurse into the directory and delete everything in the directory before you can delete the directory.

As @Audrius said, you must first delete all files in a directory, and all directories in a directory, before you can delete the directory.

The print statement is not executing because the program is erroring out.
If the file's 'delete' implementation is sane, you should be seeing an error message; have you suppressed errors in some way?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you can't remove a directory if contains something. So you must delete recursively the content of directory!

In java 7:

```
public class DeleteDirVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

private Path baseDir;

public DeleteDirVisitor() {
}

/**
 * If baseDir is specified all the subdirectory will be deleted but not basedir
 * 
 * @param baseDir
 */
public DeleteDirVisitor(Path baseDir) {
    this.baseDir = baseDir;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException e) throws IOException {
    if ((baseDir == null) || !dir.equals(baseDir)) {
        Files.delete(dir);
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    Files.delete(file);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

}

And use:

```
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(new File("Your Path").getAbsolutePath()), new DeleteDirVisitor());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileUtils.deleteDirectory() method in Apache Commons IO

Comment: Seems a bit extreme to use an entire dependency for only 1 method, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 I use this code to delete a folder and everything underneath it:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("tmp");
    if (Files.exists(path)) {
        List<Path> allFiles = new ArrayList<Path>();
        Files.walk(path).forEach(pa -> allFiles.add(pa));
        Collections.reverse(allFiles);
        allFiles.forEach(pa -> {try {System.out.println("deleting " + pa);Files.delete(pa);} catch(IOException e){}});
    }
```

Remove the System.out in the last line for silent deletion.